# cardano-cli is marked as depricated. Is there a replacement or is that what we are supposed to use?

Tags: cardano-cli

I see that the [cardano-cli](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-cli) is marked as deprecated.
Can someone tell me what is being used in it's place?
If there is no replacement right now then I would like to know that please.
Just trying to direct my time and attention most productively as I try and get oriented to developing on Cardano.
Much thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong `cardano-cli`. It you go to the [cardano-node](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node) repo, one of the components is the real, current and maintained `cardano-cli`.

Comment: Thank you @erik-de-castro-lopo, I wonder how it is possible to request that a notice of redirection can be placed in the README.md of the old deprecated repository?

Comment: I will look into it.